# how to distinct below result using java

Tags: java, spring, jpa

How to distinct below result using java? My code is as per below:

```
Page<Object[]> datasetresults=repository.findtest(tid,
                    PageRequest.of(page, per_page, Sort.by(s, sort)));

for (Object[] object : datasetresults.getContent()) {
    if (object[0] instanceof onetable ) {
        onetable onetable = (onetable) object[0];
        TestBean test = new TestBean();
    }   
}
```

I need to distinct using `tid` to get one unique result set.

Comment: What do you mean with "distinct"? like "onetable" and "twotable" could be the same object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To distinct the results based on the "tid" column and get a unique result set, you can use a Set to keep track of unique tid values while iterating through the datasetresults. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```python
Page<Object[]> datasetresults = repository.findtest(tid, PageRequest.of(page, per_page, Sort.by(s, sort)));

// Create a Set to keep track of unique tid values
Set<Long> uniqueTids = new HashSet<>();

for (Object[] object : datasetresults.getContent()) {
    if (object[0] instanceof onetable && object[1] instanceof twotable) {
        onetable onetable = (onetable) object[0];
        twotable twotable = (twotable) object[1];

        // Check if the tid is unique
        if (uniqueTids.add(onetable.getTid())) {
            // This tid is unique, process the result
            TestBean test = new TestBean();

            // Add your code here to process the unique result
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, we use a Set called uniqueTids to keep track of unique "tid" values. Before processing each result, we check if the "tid" is already in the set using uniqueTids.add(onetable.getTid()). If it's a new "tid," we process the result. This ensures that only unique "tid" values are processed, giving you a distinct result set based on "tid."

Comment: i have another issue that given query return 10 same tid and my query is pegeble and per query count is 10.my case is after distinct it return only one my other data not pick form there any chance for that.
ex:order by onetable .tid asc fetch first 10 rows only